# SQL Oracle - Merge more rows into one in same table (updating one, deleting others)

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, duplicates

I have this example table

```
PK_HASH | PERSON_ID | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO  | CREATION_DATE | NAME  | SURNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
456a8ed1| 000001    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 03.01.2016    | John  | Smith   |
a48e4b22| 000001    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 04.01.2016    | James | Smith   |
788fee89| 000001    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 05.01.2016    | James | null    |
42cba184| 000001    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 12.01.2016    | null  | null    |
5bcc48ad| 000002    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 03.01.2016    | Mike  | Legend  |
e48da448| 000003    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 03.01.2016    | Karl  | Rogel   |
889775ea| 000003    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 05.01.2016    | Carl  | null    |
```

Is it possible to prepare some merge SQL-Command for Oracle that the result will be

```
PK_HASH | PERSON_ID | VALID_FROM | VALID_TO  | CREATION_DATE | NAME  | SURNAME |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
456a8ed1| 000001    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 03.01.2016    | James | Smith   |
5bcc48ad| 000002    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 03.01.2016    | Mike  | Legend  |
e48da448| 000003    | 01.01.2016 | 31.01.2016| 03.01.2016    | Carl  | Rogel   |
```

What it means:

- The data should be grouped with pair of columns (PERSON_ID, VALID_FROM)
- Only one unique row with the **lowest** CREATION_DATE should stay for each PERSON_ID, VALID_FROM
- If there is some change of NAME or SURNAME the value shuold be changed/merged into this one row (Like for 000001: John -> James, or 000003: Karl -> Carl)
- If there is a 'null' value - this is no change and needs to be ignored.
- So the NAME or SURNAME with highest CREATION_DATE should be merged into one unique row with the lowest CREATION_DATE (expect of 'null' values)

I tried to prepare some MERGE command but really not sure if is possible to make it with this.

I need to change the content of table, I do not need some result-set. So, some updates and deletes will be needed.

@Please do not try to understand data in table. It is fictive and only used to describe the problematic

Thank you very much for each help

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy enough to achieve through the use of analytic functions:

```
    with sample_data as (select '456a8ed1' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('03/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'John' name, 'Smith' surname from dual union all
                         select 'a48e4b22' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'James' name, 'Smith' surname from dual union all
                         select '788fee89' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('05/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'James' name, null surname from dual union all
                         select '42cba184' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('12/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, null name, null surname from dual union all
                         select '5bcc48ad' pk_hash, 2 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('03/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'Mike' name, 'Legend' surname from dual union all
                         select 'e48da448' pk_hash, 3 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('03/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'Karl' name, 'Rogel' surname from dual union all
                         select '889775ea' pk_hash, 3 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('05/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'Carl' name, null surname from dual)
    -- end of mimicking a table called "sample_data" containing your data. You wouldn't need this, since you have your table.
    -- See SQL below:
    select pk_hash,
           person_id,
           valid_from,
           valid_to,
           creation_date,
           latest_name name,
           latest_surname surname
    from   (select pk_hash,
                   person_id,
                   valid_from,
                   valid_to,
                   creation_date,
                   row_number() over (partition by person_id, valid_from order by creation_date) rn,
                   last_value(name ignore nulls) over (partition by person_id, valid_from order by creation_date
                                                       rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) latest_name,
                   last_value(surname ignore nulls) over (partition by person_id, valid_from order by creation_date
                                                          rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) latest_surname
            from   sample_data)
    where  rn = 1;

    PK_HASH   PERSON_ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO   CREATION_DATE NAME  SURNAME
    -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ----- -------
    456a8ed1          1 01.01.2016 31.01.2016 03.01.2016    James Smith  
    5bcc48ad          2 01.01.2016 31.01.2016 03.01.2016    Mike  Legend 
    e48da448          3 01.01.2016 31.01.2016 03.01.2016    Carl  Rogel  

The `row_number()` function labels each row in the set (in this case, the set is across person_id and valid_from, and ordered by creation_date) with a number.

The `last_value()` function is simply finding the last non-null value in the specified columns across all rows in the set, ordered by the creation_date.

Then you just filter the results to pick the first row.
```

---

Here's a test case showing how you could use the above query to do the update/delete as part of a [merge](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/merge-enhancements-10g#delete_clause) statement:

**Create table with data in it:**

```
create table sample_data as
select '456a8ed1' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('03/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'John' name, 'Smith' surname from dual union all
select 'a48e4b22' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('04/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'James' name, 'Smith' surname from dual union all
select '788fee89' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('05/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'James' name, null surname from dual union all
select '42cba184' pk_hash, 1 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('12/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, null name, null surname from dual union all
select '5bcc48ad' pk_hash, 2 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('03/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'Mike' name, 'Legend' surname from dual union all
select 'e48da448' pk_hash, 3 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('03/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'Karl' name, 'Rogel' surname from dual union all
select '889775ea' pk_hash, 3 person_id, to_date('01/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_from, to_date('31/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') valid_to, to_date('05/01/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') creation_date, 'Carl' name, null surname from dual;
```

**Run the merge statement to do the update and deletes:**

```
merge into sample_data tgt
using (select pk_hash,
              person_id,
              valid_from,
              valid_to,
              creation_date,
              row_number() over (partition by person_id, valid_from order by creation_date) rn,
              last_value(name ignore nulls) over (partition by person_id, valid_from order by creation_date
                                                  rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) latest_name,
              last_value(surname ignore nulls) over (partition by person_id, valid_from order by creation_date
                                                     rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) latest_surname
       from   sample_data) src
  on (tgt.pk_hash = src.pk_hash)
when matched then
  update set tgt.name = src.latest_name,
             tgt.surname = src.latest_surname
  -- need to update all the rows, in order to delete the ones we're not interested in, otherwise they
  -- won't be seen by the delete statement since we're basing the delete on the src.rn column:
  delete where src.rn != 1;

commit;
```

**Output:**

```
select * from sample_data;

PK_HASH   PERSON_ID VALID_FROM VALID_TO   CREATION_DATE NAME  SURNAME
-------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ----- -------
456a8ed1          1 01.01.2016 31.01.2016 03.01.2016    James Smith  
5bcc48ad          2 01.01.2016 31.01.2016 03.01.2016    Mike  Legend 
e48da448          3 01.01.2016 31.01.2016 03.01.2016    Carl  Rogel
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. I need to check what is behind. I do not know this analytics tool. Problem is that I really need to change the content of table from 7 rows to 3 rows. So some updates and deletes are needed. Sorry, maybe my question was not clear with this. I will updated it. But in any case thanks.

Comment: Analytic functions are awesome- they allow you to access other rows in the result set without collapsing the rows (unlike aggregate queries). I highly recommend that you research them. As for your actual requirement; I'll work on that later, when I'm at a computer.

Comment: I've added a test case into my answer, demonstrating how you can do the update and delete of the rows in a single Merge statement. Hopefully you can take that away and make it fit your requirement.

Comment: Yes, it's works :) Brilliant. I adapt it to my tables and can see good results. In any case, I need to check the oracle docu, becuase as mainly it's self explanatory i do not understand the part "rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following" but I will check it. One more time thank you very much for help!!!

Comment: With Analytic functions, you (usually) get the option to choose the window over which the function applies. It can be based on rows or range. In the case above, I wanted the last_value of the group, regardless of what the current row was, so I specified rows between unbounded preceding (ie all rows before the current row) and unbounded following (ie all rows after the current row), so the function is effectively worked over all rows in the group. You can see the effect this has by changing the "unbounded following" to "current row" and rerunning just the source select statement.

Comment: Btw, Connor McDonald has made a series of videos about analytic functions, which I recommend you check out: https://connormcdonald.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/kiss-video-series-for-analytic-functions/